# Laravel 4 - how to use the package class as a queue worker

Tags: queue, laravel, beanstalkd

I have built my first Laravel 4 package.

I have used artisan to create the structure.

I need to use the package to process a queue (as the worker).

I am using the builtin Beanstalk queue and have it configured and I am able to add to the queue.

What is the correct syntax to add the correct path to the class that I would like to use to process the queue.

I can get this working if the class is saved here **/app/controllers/TestClass.php** ( beacuse this gets autoloaded)

Example:

```php
Route::get('/addtoqueue', function()
{
    $message = "This is a test message";
    Queue::push('TestClass', array('message' => $message));
    return 'Added to Queue';
});
```

But what should I put in as the class in the queue if the class is in a package?
This file is in workbench:
**workbench\vendor\package\src\Vendor\Package**

My package composer file contains

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Qwickli\\Tika": "src/"
    }
},
```

Eg.
    Queue::push('vendor\package\TestClass', array('message' => $message));

When I run php artisan queue:listen it correctly picks up the items in the queue and but it does NOT find the class (in the package) that I would like to use process the queue.
For some reason the class is not being loaded (or autoloaded) and I don't know how to make that happen.

Thanks for all and any help

Comment: This may be a workbench related problem.  Have you tried the same without the package in the workbench?  (i.e. in the vendor/Vendor/Package directory)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your package classes are not been autoloaded.

Try to access your package folder, **workbench/vendor/package** and run a **compsoer update**. If your composer "autoload" settings are correct, this should work.